# supervisorctl 3.3.1 http://localhost:9001 refused connection

Tags: 16.04, supervisor

```
root@dev-demo-karl:/srv/www# supervisord -v
3.3.1
```

Trying to get `supervisorctl` working:

```
root@dev-demo-karl:/srv/www# supervisorctl
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

My config:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[supervisorctl]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently there are required fields for the configuration file for version 3.0 and upwards http://supervisord.org/configuration.html

`[inet_http_server]` is required:

> A TCP host:port value or (e.g. 127.0.0.1:9001) on which supervisor
>   will listen for HTTP/XML-RPC requests. supervisorctl will use XML-RPC
>   to communicate with supervisord over this port. To listen on all
>   interfaces in the machine, use :9001 or *:9001.
>
> Default: No default.
>
> Required: Yes.
>
> Introduced: 3.0

Also [rpcinterface:supervisor] is required as it complains.

So my configuration must look like so:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[supervisorctl]

[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

Now it connects.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was getting mad of that error, but your answer really helped me :)

Answer (score 6):

At first You should start `supervisord` with `-c` flag and point the cfg file.

`sudo supervisord -c /path/to/config/file`

after that run `supervisorctl`

Try to run `supervisord` with `sudo` to make sure this is not premission issue. If everything works right You may start the app without the `sudo`.

`-c` flag may be needed with `supervisorctl` as well if I remember correct, but I'm not sure its necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to check the following if you get the **`http://localhost:9001 refused connection`** error.

1. Make sure `supervisord` is running
2. Have these enabled (uncommented) in `supervisord.conf` file:
   a)

   ```
   [inet_http_server]         
   port=127.0.0.1:9001
   ```

   b)

   ```
   [supervisorctl]
   serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001
   ```

   c)

   ```
   [rpcinterface:supervisor]
   supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
   ```

**Note:** The host and port of the inet server and the one which supervisorctl is trying to connect to should be the same.

Comment: I answered the same here as well: https://superuser.com/a/1303773/353685

Answer (score 0):

By Default inet_http_server is turned off in supervisor config.
You need to enable if if exist or add the following lines if it doesn't

[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001

Then restart Supervisord; 
You should be all set
sudo `supervisorctl status` should show processes with corresponding statuses

Comment: Nothing new compared to the accepted error